# Learn about file system filters / minifilters

Tags: windows, filesystems, windows-server, minifilter

I’m looking for resources that will grant me a deeper understanding of file system filters / mini filters.

I’d like to learn more about these more advanced layers of the OS, but details seem scant.

Searching for details on individual filters as given by a command like ‘FLTMC’ yields few results - maybe I’m just not searching for information correctly.

I was hoping the experts here could point me in the right direction in regards to books, documentation, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some useful resources:

1. [Microsoft Documentation on File System Filter Drivers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/about-file-system-filter-drivers)
2. [Microsoft documentation on Minifilter model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/filter-manager-concepts)
3. [Minifilter sample projects by Microsoft](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/filesys/miniFilter)
4. [System Filter Tutorial on CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43586/File-System-Filter-Driver-Tutorial)
5. [Minifilter Tutorial on OSR](https://www.osr.com/nt-insider/2017-issue2/introduction-standard-isolation-minifilters/)
6. [OSR Kernel Development Forum](https://community.osr.com/), there is also a [section dedicated to Filter and Minifilter programming](https://community.osr.com/categories/ntfsd)

Comment: Thanks for this, Flavio.  I see your name everywhere, keep it up!

Comment: You are welcome. If the answer solved your question, please mark it as an accepted solution.