# Can we monitor windows network information in realtime using minifilters?

Tags: networking, network-programming, driver, windows-kernel, minifilter

I am trying to write a [minifilter that more or less captures everything that happens in the kernel](https://github.com/sn99/fsfilter-rs) and was wondering if I could also capture "URLs"/network information; I stumbled upon [windivert](https://github.com/basil00/Divert) which seems to be using a `.sys` driver and also [another thread](https://community.osr.com/discussion/292410/get-url-of-browser-window-on-file-access-in-minifilter) which says we cannot get URLs in driver mode which leaves me a bit confused.  If it is true then how does `windivert` do it?

I understand there is something called [network redirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/basic-architecture-of-a-network-redirector) under minifilters on learn.microsoft.com which uses a `dll` and `.sys` file (same as `windivert`), but I could [not find any resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60891089/learn-about-file-system-filters-minifilters) that can help make me one.

Is there a better way to capture all visited URLs in real time?

Thanks in advance for any help or directions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [Windows Filtering Platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fwp/windows-filtering-platform-start-page) and [Filtering Platform Callout Drivers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/network/introduction-to-windows-filtering-platform-callout-drivers), which WinDivert is utilizing. This gives you the data that goes out over the wire, so for plain old HTTP over port 80 you can parse the requests to obtain the URL. This won't work for HTTPS since you're getting encrypted data over the wire; you'd have to implement some kind of MITM interception technique to handle that.

Comment: Oh okay, so this is very different from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/basic-architecture-of-a-network-redirector? If I understand correctly.

Comment: Yes. IFS is for filesystem filters whereas WFP is for network filters.